# Adding numbers in the same indices in list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a list `a=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]`. I want to create a new list, `b` with each value in the new list being the sum of all values *in that index location* of each sub-list.
So in this case it would be `[15,18,21,24]` (1+5+9,  2+6+10,   3+7+11,   4+8+12)
. This is what my code looks like at the moment.

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    b.append(sum(b[i] for b in a))
print(b)
>>> [15, 18, 21, 24]
```

I tried to use list comprehension to simplify into:

`b=[sum([c[i]] for c in a) for i in range(len(a)+1)]`

however I get an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

Ive tried googling the problem, but all I can find is people adding lists to integers. In this code it should only be adding integers (`a[c[i]]`). Whatve I done wrong?

EDIT: as Marc Ittel pointed out, there `[c[i]]` should just be `c[i]`. However as Yatu pointed out, using `map` and `zip` is much simpler.
Also as everyone has pointed out, it should *not* be `len(a)+1` but rather `len(a[0])`

Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using python's built-ins:

```
list(map(sum,zip(*a)))
#[15, 18, 21, 24]
```

Your approach produces the expected result, not sure how you defined `b` though? If it is an empty list `b=[]`, this works fine.
Also, are you sure about this for - `for i in range(len(a)+1)`?. Shouldn't you be iterating over as many items as you have in the *inner lists*?

Your list comprehension should be:

```
[sum(b[i] for b in a) for i in range(4)]
# [15, 18, 21, 24]
```

In your code, you have `[c[i]]` in the inner level. You're generating a list of lists which you don't need. Just index the list and keep the integer `b[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code might suit your need:

```py
[sum(items) for items in zip(*a)]
```

Comment: No map. No range. This is what I would have wrote.

Answer (score 1):

in the `sum`, you were trying to add lists, removing the brackets solves your problem.

Also, `i` end at `len(a[0])`, not `len(a)+1`

```py
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
>>> [sum(c[i] for c in a) for i in range(len(a[0]))]
[15, 18, 21, 24]
```